# Scale Keyframes Together From "Medium Point"

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have two key frames in order to make an object change location.  I decided to make it move faster, so I want to scale the key frames together.  However, when you select them and scale, both key frames will grow closer to each other, but they also start moving towards frame 0.
I want to scale both keys so that they move towards the middle of the original distance between them.  This would be like scaling two objects using the medium origin in the 3D view.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Mesh scaling and Graph scaling have pivot point option on the top of the graph window.  Look for the pivot point on the graph editor.  Bounding box pivot might be a good choice for you.  At the moment Blender is busy on my machine.  So maybe I can take a snapshot later.  You probably can find it.

Comment: Thanks man!  Nice - answering others' questions while Blender is at work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Dope Sheet*, the position of the 2D cursor (the blue line) will be the pivot point:

[image]

As  atomicbezierslinger says, if you switch to the *Graph Editor* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) you'll have the choice between *Bounding Box Center, 2D Cursor* and *Individual Centers*:

[image]

if you want the middle of your selected keyframes to be the pivot point, choose *Bounding Box Center*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!  That's exactly what I needed!